# (Chart.js) Bar chart context.element.height is NaN at initial render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm using `chart.js` and `vue-chartjs`. (vue version is 2.6)

I want the gradient background color bar chart to match the height of each individual bar.

What I want to achieve like this:
[expected results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjDN5.png)

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430216/horizontal-gradient-for-every-single-bar-in-group-chart-js) stackoverflow question when I was researching solutions, and wrote the backgroundColor property of datasets with [Option Context](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#option-context) as follows.

```js
datasets: [
  {
    label: "Data One",
    backgroundColor: (context) => {
      console.log("element", context.element)
      console.log("y", context.element.y)
      console.log("height", context.element.height)

      if (!context.element.y || !context.element.height) {
        return;
      }
      const { ctx } = context.chart;
      const { y, height } = context.element;
      const background_1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(
        0,
        y,
        0,
        y + height
      );

      background_1.addColorStop(0.4, "#55BBDD");
      background_1.addColorStop(1, "#C8E8F6");

      return background_1;
    },
    data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11],
  },
],
```

Also, I have a [codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-initial-render-error-linear-gradient-7jqqp5?file=/src/components/Bar.vue) here.

Maybe the first visit will not cause any problems.
But If you reload your browser inside codesandbox, all bars will be black.
And also I'm having the same problem with my own vue app.

[unexpected results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHHiv.png)

As you can see, `console.log("height", context.element.height)` outputs `NaN` at initial render.
So `!context.element.height` is always `true` and returns so never goes down.

If you hover each bar, only hovered bar changes to gradient backgroundColor correctly.

Do you have any idea to fix this?

Thank you.